# image float left and text right (not in the bottom of the image)

Tags: html, css

I have a problem in a li that I want to remove the text in the bottom of the thumbnail image.

https://jsfiddle.net/tyrc2ufj/

I want the text to stay on the right of image. I don't want it in the bottom of it. What is wrong?

html

```css
*{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style: none;
}

#menu2 { 
 background-color: #fff;
 border:1px solid #D4DFE7;
 height: 100%;
 width: 200px;
 float: left;
 padding: 5px; 
}

#menu2 li{
 display:inline-block;
 margin-bottom:10px;
 width:100%;
 clear:both;
}
#menu2 li img{
 float:left;
 width:64px;
 margin-right:10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu2">
    <ul>
    
        <li><img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/windows-8-metro-style/128/pencil.png">The most common type of pencil casing is of thin wood, usually hexagonal in section but sometimes cylindrical, permanently bonded to the core. Similar permanent casings may be constructed of other materials such as plastic or paper.</li>
        
         <li><img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/windows-8-metro-style/128/pencil.png">The most common type of pencil casing is of thin wood, usually hexagonal in section but sometimes cylindrical, permanently bonded to the core. Similar permanent casings may be constructed of other materials such as plastic or paper.</li>
    
    </ul>    
</div>
```

Thank you friends!

Comment: that's what float does. You would be better off putting the img in a containing inline-block div and have the text in a seperate one (or li, etc)

Comment: thank you! I will try this way

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna consider the image to be always fixed and the text to be fluid, you can use a fixed-fluid layout as said below:

```css
* {margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; font-family: 'Segoe UI';}
ul {margin: 15px;}
li {position: relative; padding-left: 65px; margin: 0 0 15px; min-height: 65px;}
li img {position: absolute; left: 0; top: 10px; width: 50px;}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/windows-8-metro-style/128/pencil.png">This is one liner.</li>
  <li><img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/windows-8-metro-style/128/pencil.png">The most common type of pencil casing is of thin wood, usually hexagonal in section but sometimes cylindrical, permanently bonded to the core. Similar permanent casings may be constructed of other materials such as plastic or paper.</li>
  <li><img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/windows-8-metro-style/128/pencil.png">The most common type of pencil casing is of thin wood, usually hexagonal in section but sometimes cylindrical, permanently bonded to the core. Similar permanent casings may be constructed of other materials such as plastic or paper. The most common type of pencil casing is of thin wood, usually hexagonal in section but sometimes cylindrical, permanently bonded to the core. Similar permanent casings may be constructed of other materials such as plastic or paper.</li>
</ul>
```

The above solution works well, but the only issue is setting a `min-height` for the `<li>` to accommodate the image and not cut or overlap it. If you are very lazy enough, then you can think of enclosing the text content inside another element with a `display: inline-block`, but it is a hassle. Won't work in responsive. My solution is **responsive** too.

I have given three examples in the above snippet.

1. With a single line / one liner.
2. With the default text you provided.
3. With double the amount of text content you originally had.